# Unable to start the Genymotion virtual device

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

In my desktop computer I've installed Oracle VM VirtualBox and Genymotion software. Then I've created a new virtual device. The problem is when I play the newly created virtual device it shows following error dialog.

[image]

I am new to this Genymotion software and I have found some guidelines from the Internet. But I have no clear idea about hoe to use this software and I am a little bit confused.

I would be much obliged if anyone please be so kind enough to help me to solve this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the last drivers for your video card.

Answer (score 0):

I had that exact same problem, what i did was

Go to https://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx to download drivers for your intel graphics card, in case you dont know about your graphics card use this link to autodetect http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics, your computer should have java installed, if not install java and reload page.

Once it identifies your card, download drivers from the link that appears.
Restart your computer and Then try running gennymotion, this time it should hopefully work.
This worked for me