# Genymotion not working when installed on VM

Tags: android, vmware, genymotion

I've got Genymotion installed on VMWware. When I try to run up a virtual device, I get the message:

> Unable to start the Genymotion virtual device. Check if your video card support OpenGL. If no, then Genymotion virtual device can not start. If yes, maybe you should update your video card drivers.
>
> Detailed information: Failed to initialize backend EGL display (error: 4).

I've searched for this and suggestions have included:

1. Try using Genymotion (already doing that!)
2. Update your video card drivers (I've already got the latest drivers)
3. The following post: [Unable to start the Genymotion virtual device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262717/unable-to-start-the-genymotion-virtual-device), but the video card is not recognised and no drivers are available.

I'm beginning to wonder if you can run Genymotion within a VM. Has anyone had this issue and, if so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

Genymotion is a VM hosting solution, so it's not surprising that you cant run it within a VM!

From the Genymotion FAQ

> Genymotion doesn't start from a virtual machine
>
> Genymotion can't be run from a virtual machine.
>
> Indeed, Genymotion needs a direct access to the hardware in order to
>   provide OpenGL acceleration.
>
> Running Genymotion from a virtual machine prevents it to directly
>   access the hardware components.
>
> So Genymotion is incompatible when installed from within VMWare,
>   Parallels, Hyper-V, VirtualPC.